# Is there any way to perform my required logic other than with recursion applied on a tree data structure?

Tags: apex, trigger, limits, recursion, algorithm

This is the most complex logic I've ever worked with in Salesforce.

I'll try to describe my requirement in simple terms.

I have a custom object which has a date field(StartDate__c), and a number ID field(Numbers__c). The number ID field contains multiple values separated by a comma.

I have a third field(PreperiodStart__c), type date, which needs to be populated by my logic. By default, ALL records receive a PreperiodStart__c value of StartDate__c minus 3 weeks.

Concept of "overlap" defines which two records should be related - and if there is a relation, the older record will contribute its PreperiodStart__c field value to the younger one's PreperiodStart__c.

Overlap is defined as such: Is the older record's StartDate__c value within the younger record's StartDate and StartDate minus 3 weeks, and do they share at least one Number__c value?

Example:

Record A : StartDate__c = 03-Nov-2023, Numbers__c = 1111,2222,3333

Record B : StartDate__c = 20-Oct-2023, Numbers__c = 3333,4444,5555

Record C : StartDate__c = 15-Oct-2023, Numbers__c = 4444,5555

Record D : StartDate__c = 01-Oct-2023, Numbers__c = 1111

Result:
Record A will receive a PreperiodStart__c from Record B StartDate__c. Why - B StartDate__c is not more than 3 weeks before A StartDate__c && A and B share at least one Numbers__c value.
However Record B is already receiving a PreperiodStart__c value from Record C, as C and B have overlap. Thus the PreperiodStart__c of C will bubble up to both B and A.
Record D does not have overlap with any of the other records.

My current solution: I order all records starting with youngest one, as long as there is a date overlap. I build a tree data structure based purely on StartDate__c and PreperiodStart__c overlap, ignoring the Numbers__c. Once the tree exists, I bubble up the PreperiodStart__c from lowest branches to the higher ones only IF there is a number__s overlap.

However this algorithm only allows me to work with maximum 16 records per tree, more than that causes heap size limit exceptions.

I'm trying to see if this logic can be performed in a non-recursive way, which would allow me to split the logic into multiple asynchronous processes and process much more data. However that would need a different data structure as I don't see how trees can be built and traversed without recursion.